# Sqlyog - multiple SQL queries

Tags: sqlyog

I have set of SQL select queries to execute and share the consolidated results in excel sheet, I'm using sqlyog to do this.

Every time I execute results are in multiple tables. Can I get the results in a single table?

```
Select * from a.table;
Select * from b.table;
```

Comment: Give some more details, like table structure of each. are the having same structure data ? won't a `join` will do ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the result in a single table you need to use JOIN's in your query.
For Example, I have a area_table and I have a height_table.
to get the result in the consolidated table I would use JOIN and write the query as:

```
Select a.*,b.* from area_table a 
Join height_table b;
```